# Detect schema change by DDL for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, schema, build-automation

I am wondering if there is a tool that can do such a thing. It can detect difference between 2 versions of DDL and automatically apply scripts if there is a change on the schema. And I want it to work for PostgreSQL.

For example, we had **v1.sql**:

```
CREATE TABLE student (  
  id int,  
  name text  
);
```

now we have **v2.sql**：

```
CREATE TABLE student (  
  id int,  
  name text,  
  nick_name text  
);
```

As you can see there is one more column added the the student table when we move from v1 to v2. So the we should generate and apply this script:

```
ALTER TABLE student ADD nick_name text;
```

The use case is like when we want to move from version to version. It will automatically update the schema if there is a change. It does not have to handle too complex situation, a simple add/drop column and table should be fine. Other things might still need to be done manually.

A CCDR strategy could always work, but we prefer not to do that way while it can be done by simply adding/dropping a column.

Comment: [Compare two similar Postgres databases for differences](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/66665/88191)

Comment: There is no way you can reliably do this. Consider the tables `student(id, name)` and `student (id, login_name)` was this a drop column and add column or was that change a "rename column". Or consider the tables `student (id, name)` and `students(id,name)`. Was this a drop table and a create table or a rename table? The distinction is important if you have data in those tables. It is impossible to get this 100% correct. The only reliable way to deal with schema migrations is to store the _change_ scripts and apply them in the correct order as needed. Tools like Liquibase help a lot with that.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for the late reply, I went for a conference. It did help a lot. :)